# Should I apologize to my former employer?

Tags: termination

2 months ago I was fired from a job that I loved due to me running late a couple of times.

I can say that

- When I was at the company (actually, it was a school) I devoted my energy and heart into what I was doing when I was working there and I don't think I did a bad job
- I lost the job due to a very unfortunate circumstance at the exact
  wrong time.

I am currently trying to sort out my own feelings about this

Part of me misses that job and I wish I could be re-hired.

I believe I did everything within my power to produce satisfactory results and I felt as if I had the perfect skill-set for the job.

I'm worried because this dismissal doesn't just do me anminjustice on my resume, but also in my opinion also compromises my future job prospects.

Should I apologize to my former employer?

Comment: Hint: "Thank you" comments are not necessary under every post here. The Stack Exchange way of saying "thanks, that helped" is to upvote. I recommend you take the [tour] and browse [help], which will explain more.

Answer (score 10):

At this time, I do not think you should apologize as you don't think that you really did anything wrong, as you glossed over what you did and are chalking it up to "Unfortunate circumstances at the exact wrong time"

I suspect that the "unfortunate circumstances" involved you getting caught doing something wrong, and the "exact wrong time" is more along the line of it being the last straw with your employer.

Eventually, an apology may help when your next potential employer checks your references and employment history.  However, to do that, you need to be able to first articulate to yourself

- What you did
- What was wrong with it
- What you should have done instead
- How it affected the person concerned
- What you learned

Then, include all of the above with a sincere expression of regrets.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, I did something wrong (I was late and I missed my employer's call later that day) and it was the last straw with my employer. I should have stayed home instead that day. I learned to always be on time...

Comment: However, I didn't do anything (ethically) wrong. I simply made the decision to go to work when I was sick, which resulted in lateness and I didn't call them upfront to tell them I was late. I don't see how I could have seen this coming back then, I endeavored to be on time with all of my might, but I failed. And I didn't take my employers call because of neglect, but because of sheer bad luck that day.

Comment: @R.Penber if you think its bad luck, you still don't fully realize why you were fired

Comment: @R.Penber The business world is a full contact sport.  Being 15 minutes early is on time, on time is late, and late is unforgivable.  Follow that rule, and you won't get into trouble.  This was obviously not the first time you were late, When you're running late, for whatever reason, you should call, and you did not.  This was not back luck or happenstance.  As I said, this is not the time to make an apology, as you still don't' realize what you did wrong.  If I had been your former employer, and got something like you just commented, It would make me think even worse of you.  Think on this.

Comment: @SaggingRufus I had strong suspicions that this would be the case, thus the tenor of my reply

Comment: I did not arrive to work on time, and I did not call beforehand to let my employer know I was late.
It was wrong, because the people at work had to wait for me.
I should have either called in and let them know I was late, or I should have stayed at home.
My employer was angry with me, because I did not respect his or her time and/or 
did not show respect for company policy.
I learned to always be on time, and/or to call in to work if I will be running late.
I am so sorry for my mistakes, and I am so sorry for any inconvenience that it might have caused you [employer].

Comment: @R.Penber Good.  just don't put "I learned", but something more along the lines, of "I was inconsiderate, and I realize that now".  Always own your mistakes.

Comment: Thank you for your help yesterday. I think I finally realize what you have been trying to tell me, today I sat down and tried to write the letter and it just flows and sounds genuine.

Answer (score 4):

> Should I apologize to my former employer?

It probably won't do you any harm. But it probably won't do you much good either - they're not going to re-hire you, and they're not going to change anything they say about the reason for your dismissal.

Therefore apologize if you feel in your heart that you let them down, but don't do it if you're expecting something in return - that's fake and nobody likes a fake.

Comment: I think I want the job back. What's wrong with that? It would not only benefit me, but I am certain that it would benefit my former employer as well. But perhaps it's still too early for that...

Answer (score 4):

If you are asking whether if apologizing will help you get unfired, that will never happen. You were fired which likely means one of three things:

1. You were warned and went through disciplinary action and still did not show improvement in their eyes.
2. You were terminated simply because you were late a couple times and your employer did not care or value you enough to do anything about it except to get rid of you.
3. It was a position where punctuality really mattered and you showed that you could not be punctual.

There is no need to apologise after the fact or any way it can help you. I would keep looking for another job. Firings happen and they are generally no big deal to prospective employers.

Comment: "Firings happen and they are generally no big deal to prospective employers." I can't speak for all employers, but I certainly care if you were fired (as opposed to laid off).  Quite often a future employer would also fire you for the same kind of behavior/lack of remediation, so they care.

Comment: Well, great. That spells that my career is over...

Comment: Not at all. There are *some* employers that will ask that during interviews and you should anserr honestly. I would say it's a 20% that will ask vs 80% that will not. You should be more worried about addressing and fixing the reasons behind you getting fired

Comment: And sure, it *will* damage your career but if you do persist and make sure this does not happen again, it will make for a good story a decade down the line.

Answer (score 0):

Actually once an employee is dismissed it is last action which is taken when employer become fully convinced that improvement in performance or conduct of individual is not possible despite repeated warning. In this case you should seriously look inwards and find out your weaknesses. In my opinion you should not  apologize with your employer for re hiring bcos it is also against your prestige and honour to continue the job after apologize. You should try to search new job bcos change of job is recurring process to raise the respect and salary.

Comment: I was only given one warning, and I didn't repeat the offense.

Comment: @R.Penber That doesn't add up. Either you got a warning and the next time you were fired, or it wasn't a warning. Also, in your question you wrote that you were fired "due to me running late a couple of times."

Comment: Yeah, somehow it's trivial now, I think I will send the company a letter and apologize for my misconduct.